# Issue while deleting folder from hdfs with java.lang.Process

Tags: java

Issue while executing hadoop command from `java.lang.Process`.

```
hadoop fs -rm -R -skipTrash pathToFolder
```

this command directly executed on unixbox is working but when I try to execute it from Process it says `'-rm -R'` unknown command.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] commandToDelete = new String[]{"hadoop", "fs","-rm -R", "-skipTrash", "hdfs://pathToFolder"};
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToDelete);
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(process.exitValue());
        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
       errorReader.close();

    }
}
```

From same location I am able to delete file but not folder any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

From  [exec(String[] cmdarray)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-)

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.
>
> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(cmdarray) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation exec(cmdarray, null, null).

So you below command is run in separate process thats why `-rm -R` is unknown command:

```
String[] commandToDelete = new String[]{"hadoop", "fs","-rm -R", "-skipTrash", "hdfs://pathToFolder"};
```

Run like below:

```
String command = "hadoop fs -rm -R -skipTrash hdfs://pathToFolder"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: how it was working for deleting a file from same location?

Comment: you can check your command for that, it must be either in same like or some of the command in that array have deleted that.

Comment: sure, will check :)

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution (that prevents your subsequent problem with space in the path) is to stay with the `String[]` form but split the arguments correctly:

```
String[] commandToDelete = new String[]{"hadoop", "fs", "-rm", "-R", "-skipTrash", "hdfs://pathToFolder"};
```