# Issue while deleting hdfs file that has space in its path, using java.lang.Process

Tags: java

I have to delete file/folder from hdfs location using `java.lang.Process` interface.
It is working when path to the file/folder doesn't have spaces.
It returns exitcode 255 when there is space in path.

```
private static int executeProcessBuilder(String commandToExecute)  {
    Process process = null;
    try {

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToExecute);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException | NullPointerException  e ) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return process.exitValue();
}
```

I tried enclosing the path in double/single quotes for example

- hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash 'hdfs://pathThatHasSpace/test.csv'
- hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash "hdfs://pathThatHasSpace/test.csv"

but no luck.

Can someone help in resolving this issue

Comment: Don't use the single-string variant of `exec()`. Use the one where [arguments are provided as individual `String` values in a `String[]` instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])).

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer : Earlier I was using String[] but it has got issue with folder delete so changed to single string.  Reference link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854813/issue-while-deleting-folder-from-hdfs-with-java-lang-process

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch : %20 didnt work, quotes I have already tried which didn't work. Let me know if I understand correctly.

Comment: I added a better answer to your original question. There is no way to handle space correctly using `Runtime.exec(String)`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for the reply, can you suggest me any other approach for same implementation, Our spring scheduler job deletes files and folders from hdfs using java.lang.Process. Path to the file is picked up from database at run time. Our current issue is it fails when path has spaces.  Spring scheduler service runs on edge node and connect to hdfs.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085 , now it is working with String[]  :)

Comment: String[] commandToDelete = new String[]{"hadoop", "fs","-rm", "-skipTrash", "path that has spaces"};